# How can I print varying number of multiple pages per sheet on Mac? (Standard layout / print multiple pages option does not suit)

Tags: safari, pdf, preview, pages, printing

I've got a bunch of pdfs containing text. Each page is of the same width, but **each page is of a different height.** Some pages only contain a few lines of text, other pages contain a lot of text.

I want to print this pdf on a Mac so that each sheet I print on is filled nicely with text. The problem is that the standard 'print multiple pages per sheet' option does not suit, as some pages of the pdf could fill their own page, whereas others are so narrow that 3 or 4 of them could be combined on one sheet.

Anyone know of a simple software / workaround that solves my problem? Thanks so much!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wait to be corrected, but I'm not convinced that any 'simple' software exists to do this easily. *(I'm wondering whether Safari will split up PDF content for printing in the same way as it does for web pages -- though of course that can cut the page in the middle of a line of text.)*

Your best bet is to manually place each PDF page onto the fixed pages of some DTP software, like Affinity Publisher, or Scribus, or InDesign. Unless you've got more than 100 pages, this shouldn't take too long.

Having written a number of python scripts that interact with MacOS's CoreGraphics, it is conceivable that a utility could be written to 'consolidate' the pages onto the pages of a new PDF; though this would require *some work*.

Comment: Thanks, I did find a solution for my problem. I ended up exporting the pdf pages as image files and placed a .html file into the folder that displays the images through a webbrowser. Printing through the webbrowser worked perfectly. Here is the .hmtl file

<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style>img{display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}</style>
</head><body>
<img src="page 1.png" style="max-width:100%;"> <br>
***enter more lines like this, with the correct file names***
</body></html>

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I did find a solution for my problem. I ended up exporting the pdf pages as image files and placed a .html file into the folder that displays the images through a webbrowser. Printing through the webbrowser worked perfectly. Here is the .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style>img{display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}</style>
</head><body>
<img src="page 1.png" style="max-width:100%;"> <br>
<!--enter more lines like this, with the correct file names-->
</body></html>
```

Comment: Nice idea. Though ideally, you'd want an automated way of adding the filenames.

Comment: Actually the pdf export function usually gives identical filenames to the files, so once the html file is set up it doesn't need to be modified between different files.

Comment: What is the exporting app? You're sure there's no way to export it better?